# What's the best way to recover from BSOD error?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I Have windows 7 premium, getting errors indicating PYTHONDLL AND PYTHON27.DLL missing, also BSOD ERROR  0x00000050, 0xFFFFFAE0066F7C18, 0X0000000000000000, 0X0000000000000005   Please give me some recommendations.

Comment: Can you get to windows desktop?  Then try re-installing python.

Comment: ERROR 0x00000050 PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA? Test RAM and HDD. Enable DEP.

Comment: Do you have a crash dump with your problem? Try looking for C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP and then if you can't look for the crash dump in C:\Windows\Minidump. Upload that to a file hosting service.

Comment: In my opinion this question is not "too broad". Yes, most BSODs can have too much solutions (all of them are "too broad"? maybe we remove BSOD tag??), but this is not the case. This BSOD has concrete solutions and was covered in 2 answers (it helped me to solve my BSOD). Also it's a "narrow" question and has enough details for being answered (BSOD first 3 codes are here, DLL names too). If I'm wrong, please tell me. So it would be good to see the question open again.

Answer (score 2):

For your Python problem, try reinstalling Python. It looks like they somehow got deleted, and you can get them back by reinstalling Python.

For your BSOD problem, check your HDD (run [Command Prompt](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Open-a-Command-Prompt-window) as Admin, and type `chkdsk`) and memory. To check memory, run either [Windows Memory diagnostic](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Diagnosing-memory-problems-on-your-computer) (F8 before Windows logo shows up and hit tab and enter) or [Memtest86](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memtest) (download it and then burn it to a disk).

If that doesn't help (it shows all clear), we will need more information to help you. Please upload your crash dump files (C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP peferably, but if that doesn't exist C:\Windows\Minidump\.dmp) to an online service like [Dropbox](https://dropbox.com/) or [OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Error 0x00000050 can occur if:

- RAM / HDD is faulty - (@justcool's answer covers this).
- Videocard is faulty - Check it's driver (4th point). Also check if there is no overheating (using tools like [GPU-Z](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/)) as overheating can cause various BSODs.
- there is no free space on HDD for page file - delete anything to free more HDD space.
- faulty service - remove/reinstall software and check if problem exists.
- bad driver - update lately installed driver. If you have plugged in new device, unplug it and check if problem exists. If you have updated driver and problem occured, roll back the driver.

Hope this helps.
[Here](http://bsodstop.ru/0x00000050-page-fault-in-nonpaged-area) is the source (if you know russian, or use [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=ru&tl=en&u=http://bsodstop.ru/0x00000050-page-fault-in-nonpaged-area) instead).